# how to manage multiple asp.net applications on one hosting with subdomains?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, launching-application

thanks for your time and attention.

I want to deploy multiple asp.net applications on same hosting with subdomains. How it should be manged ?

I just created a subdomain and deploy application in its folder; when I tried to access application with subdomain it shows the following error:

> An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error
>   from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however,
>   be viewed by browsers running on the
>   local server machine.

Pleae guide me.

thanks

Comment: Change the error mode from RemoteOnly to Off in the web.config to see the actual error message, then you'll get more help.

Comment: It is Off but it still shows the same message and same page. Can you please see http://totelabelingsystem.sofhof.com/admin/default.aspx and guide me.

 totelabelingsystem.sofhof.com is my subdomain. The application has admin folder and in this folder I have page default.aspx

Plz advice

Answer (score 1):

You need to make each application folder a web application.  How to do that depends on your hosting situation.